# BinaryTree search function

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

The program should ask the user to enter the ID number of the employee he or she wants to search for. If it is found the employee of that ID number is displayed. I can display the ID numbers and employees just by using the display functions but I can't figure out how to make the search function work and display the employees.

BINARYTREE

```
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H
#define BINARYTREE_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// This class is a template class that creates a binary
// tree that can hold values of any data type. It has 
// functions to insert a node, delete a node, display the
// tree In Order, Pre Order and Post Order, search for a 
// value, count the number of total nodes, left nodes, 
// and a function to determine the height of the tree.

template <class T>
class BinaryTree
{
private:
    struct TreeNode
    {
        T value;            // The value in the node
        TreeNode *left;     // Pointer to left child node
        TreeNode *right;    // Pointer to right child node
    };

    TreeNode *root;         // Pointer to the root node

    // Private member functions
    void insert(TreeNode *&, TreeNode *&);
    void destroySubTree(TreeNode *);
    void deleteNode(T, TreeNode *&);
    void makeDeletion(TreeNode *&);
    void displayInOrder(TreeNode *) const;
    void displayPreOrder(TreeNode *) const;
    void displayPostOrder(TreeNode *) const;

public:
    // Constructor
    BinaryTree()
    { root = NULL; }

    // Destructor
    ~BinaryTree()
    { destroySubTree(root); }

    // Binary tree operations
    void insertNode(T);
    bool searchNode(int);
    void remove(T);

    void displayPreOrder() const
    { displayPreOrder(root); }

    void displayInOrder() const
    { displayInOrder(root); }

    void displayPostOrder() const
    { displayPostOrder(root); }

};

//*********************************************************
// insert function accepts a TreeNode pointer and a       *
// pointer to a node. The function inserts the node into  *
// the tree pointer to by the TreeNode pointer. This      *
// function is call recursively.                          *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::insert(TreeNode *&nodePtr, TreeNode *&newNode)
{
    if (nodePtr == NULL)
        nodePtr = newNode;              // Insert the node
    else if (newNode->value < nodePtr->value)
        insert(nodePtr->left, newNode); // Search the left branch
    else
        insert(nodePtr->right, newNode);// Search the right branch
}

//*********************************************************
// insertNode creates a new node to hold item as its value*
// and passes it to the insert function.                  *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
 void BinaryTree<T>::insertNode(T item)
 {
     TreeNode *newNode;     // Pointer to a new node

     // Create anew node and store num in it
     newNode = new TreeNode;
     newNode->value = item;
     newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;

     // Insert the node
     insert(root, newNode);
 }

//**********************************************************
// destroySubTree is called by the destructor. It deletes  *
// all nodes in the tree.                                  *
//**********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::destroySubTree(TreeNode *nodePtr)
{
     if (nodePtr)
     {
         if (nodePtr->left)
             destroySubTree(nodePtr->left);
         if (nodePtr->right)
             destroySubTree(nodePtr->right);
         delete nodePtr;
     }
}

//**********************************************************
// searchNode determines if a value is present in the tree.*
// If so, the function returns true. Otherwise it returns  *
// false.
//**********************************************************
template <class T>
bool BinaryTree<T>::searchNode(T item)
{
    TreeNode *nodePtr = root;

    while (nodePtr)
    {
        if (nodePtr->value == item)
            return true;
        else if (item < nodePtr->value)
            nodePtr = nodePtr->left;
        else
            nodePtr = nodePtr->right;
    }
    return false;
}

//*********************************************************
// remove calls deleteNode to delete the node whode value *
// member is the same as num                              *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::remove(T item)
{
    deleteNode(item, root);
}

//*********************************************************
// deleteNode deletes the node whose value member is the  *
// same as num                                            *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::deleteNode(T item, TreeNode *&nodePtr)
{
    if (item < nodePtr->value)
        deleteNode(item, nodePtr->left);
    else if (item > nodePtr->value)
        deleteNode(item, nodePtr->right);
    else
        makeDeletion(nodePtr);
}

//*********************************************************
// makeDeletion takes a reference to apointer to the node *
// that is to be deleted. The node is removed and the     *
// branches of the tree below the node are reattached     *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::makeDeletion(TreeNode *&nodePtr)
{
    // Define a temporary pointer to use in reattaching
    // the left subtree
    TreeNode *tempNodePtr;

    if (nodePtr == NULL)
        cout << "Cannot delete empty node.\n";
    else if (nodePtr->right == NULL)
    {
        tempNodePtr = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->left;    // Reattach the left child
        delete tempNodePtr;
    }
    else if (nodePtr->left == NULL)
    {
        tempNodePtr = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->right;   // Reattach the right child
        delete tempNodePtr;
    } 

}
//*********************************************************
// The displayInOrder function displays the values in the *
// subtree pointed to by nodePtr, via inorder traversal   *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::displayInOrder(TreeNode *nodePtr) const
{
    if (nodePtr)
    {
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->left);
        cout << nodePtr->value.getEmpID() << "  "
             << nodePtr->value.getEmpName() << endl;
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->right);
    }
}
//*********************************************************
// The displayPreOrder function displays the values in the*
// subtree pointed to by nodePtr, via Preorder traversal  *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::displayPreOrder(TreeNode *nodePtr) const
{
    if (nodePtr)
    {
        cout << nodePtr->value.getEmpID() << "  "
             << nodePtr->value.getEmpName() << endl;
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->left);
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->right);
    }
}
//*********************************************************
// displayPostOrder function displays the values in the   *
// subtree pointed to by nodePtr, via Postorder traversal *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::displayPostOrder(TreeNode *nodePtr) const
{
    if (nodePtr)
    {
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->left);
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->right);
        cout << nodePtr->value.getEmpID() << "  "
             << nodePtr->value.getEmpName() << endl;
    }
}
#endif
```

EMPLOYEEINFO

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEEINFO_H
#define EMPLOYEEINFO_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// This class has two data members to hold the employee ID
// and the name of the employee.

class EmployeeInfo
{
private:
    int empID;      // To hold employee ID number
    string empName; // To hold employee name

public:
    // Default Constructor
    EmployeeInfo();

    // Constructor
    EmployeeInfo(int, string);

    // Mutators
    void setEmpID(int);
    void setEmpName(string);

    // Accessors
    int getEmpID();
    string getEmpName();

    // Overloaded operator. This works directly with
    // the insert function of BinaryTree.h more specifically
    // line 71. *For my knowledge*
    bool operator < (const EmployeeInfo &e)
    {
        if (empID < e.empID)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Overloaded operator for the search function
    bool operator == (const EmployeeInfo &e)
    {
        if (empID == e.empID)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

};
#endif

#include "EmployeeInfo.h"

//*********************************************************
// Default constructor intializes the data members        *
//*********************************************************
EmployeeInfo::EmployeeInfo()
{
    empName = "";
    empID = 0;  
}

//*********************************************************
// Constructor sets the data members                      *
//*********************************************************
EmployeeInfo::EmployeeInfo(int ID, string name)
{
    empName = name;
    empID = ID; 
}

//*********************************************************
// setEmpID stores the employee ID number                 *
//*********************************************************
void EmployeeInfo::setEmpID(int ID)
{
    empID = ID;
}

//*********************************************************
// setEmpName stores the full name of the employee        *
//*********************************************************
void EmployeeInfo::setEmpName(string name)
{
    empName = name;
}

//*********************************************************
// getEmpID returns the employee ID number                *
//*********************************************************
int EmployeeInfo::getEmpID()
{
    return empID;
}

//*********************************************************
// getEmpName returns the full name of the employee       *
//*********************************************************
string EmployeeInfo::getEmpName()
{
    return empName;
}
```

MAIN

```
#include "EmployeeInfo.h"
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // Create an instance of BinaryTree
    BinaryTree<EmployeeInfo> tree;

    // Create an EmployeeInfo object
    EmployeeInfo emp1(1021, "John Williams");
    EmployeeInfo emp2(1057, "Bill Witherspoon");
    EmployeeInfo emp3(2487, "Jennifer Twain");
    EmployeeInfo emp4(3769, "Sophia Lancaster");
    EmployeeInfo emp5(1017, "Debbie Reece");
    EmployeeInfo emp6(1275, "George McMullen");
    EmployeeInfo emp7(1899, "Ashley Smith");
    EmployeeInfo emp8(4218, "Josh Plemmons");    

    tree.insertNode(emp1);
    tree.insertNode(emp2);
    tree.insertNode(emp3);
    tree.insertNode(emp4);
    tree.insertNode(emp5);
    tree.insertNode(emp6);
    tree.insertNode(emp7);
    tree.insertNode(emp8);

    // Search for an employee
    char again = 'y';       // To hold yes
    int id;                 // To hold ID number from user

    cout << "Would you like to search for an employee?\n";
    cout << "Enter Y for yes or N for No: ";
    cin >> again;
    if (again)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Enter the ID number of the employee: ";
            cin >> id;
            // Create an EmployeeInfo object to store the user's 
            // search parameters
            EmployeeInfo info;
            info.setEmpID(id);

            // If search finds what the user entered display the 
            // corresponding employee
            if (tree.searchNode(info))
            {
                cout << info.getEmpName() << endl; // Not right?
            }
            else
                cout << "ID not found!" << endl;

            cout << "Would you like to search for an employee?\n";
            cout << "Enter Y for yes or N for No: ";
            cin >> again;
        }while (again == tolower('Y'));
    }


    // Display in order
    tree.displayInOrder();
    cout << endl;
    tree.displayPreOrder();
    cout << endl;
    tree.displayPostOrder();
}
```

Ok I changed the code up to get the bool to work and the `if (tree.searchNode(info))` but I don't think the `cout` statement is right. Can someone look at my `searchNode` function and how I called it in main and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies here

```
    info.setEmpID(1021);
    info.setEmpID(1057);
    info.setEmpID(2487);
    info.setEmpID(3769);
    info.setEmpID(1017);
    info.setEmpID(1275);
    info.setEmpID(1899);
    info.setEmpID(4218);

    info.setEmpName("John Williams");
    info.setEmpName("Bill Witherspoon");
    info.setEmpName("Jennifer Twain");
    info.setEmpName("Sophia Lancaster");
    info.setEmpName("Debbie Reece");
    info.setEmpName("George McMullen");
    info.setEmpName("Ashley Smith");
    info.setEmpName("Josh Plemmons");
```

You are not adding anything to info but every time you call `setEmpName()` you are updating `info` object.

You can make few changes in `searchNode` method as below

```
template <class T>
```

bool BinaryTree::searchNode(T &item)
{
    TreeNode *nodePtr = root;

```
while (nodePtr)
{
    if (nodePtr->value == item)
    {
        item.setEmpName(nodePtr->value.getEmpName());
        return true;
    }
    else if (item < nodePtr->value)
        nodePtr = nodePtr->left;
    else
        nodePtr = nodePtr->right;
}
return false;
```

}

In `main()` method

```
do
        {
            cout << "Enter the ID number of the employee: ";
            cin >> id;
            BinaryTree<EmployeeInfo> temp;
            if ((temp=tree.searchNode(id))!=NULL) 
            {
                cout << temp.getEmpName() << endl;
            }
            else{
                cout<<"ID not found"<<endl;
             }
            cout << "Would you like to search for an employee?\n";
            cout << "Enter Y for yes or N for No: ";
            cin >> again;
        }while (again == tolower('Y'));
```

//New changes...
Made change in declaration of `searchNode(T)` to `searchNode(T &)`...In your new code the name of employee found was not set in `info` thats why when you are trying to print `EmpName` there was not output...So the change is pass the reference of `EmployeeInfo` to `searchitem(T &)`

template 
bool BinaryTree::searchNode(T &item)
{
    TreeNode *nodePtr = root;

```
while (nodePtr)
{
    if (nodePtr->value == item)
    {
        item.setEmpName(nodePtr->value.getEmpName());
        return true;
    }
    else if (item < nodePtr->value)
        nodePtr = nodePtr->left;
    else
        nodePtr = nodePtr->right;
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: I get error codes after making these changes. I have put them at the end of my code

Comment: Ahh got that... `searchNode()` accepts EmployeeInfo type parameter and we are passing `int` which is causing the error....`searchNode(T item)` to `searchNode(int item)`....that should work...

Comment: Ok I made my function header in BinaryTree.h read `T searchNode(int)` the function definition reads `T BinaryTree<T>::searchNode(int item` when I do this it tells me that my if statement for the search function in main `!= NULL` no operator matches these operands.. I will build and update with new error codes

Comment: Take a look now. The program runs but doesn't display the corresponding employee